# Can I load views from inside another partial view in Angular JS 1.5?

Tags: angularjs

So I am already in a partial view(..someURL.aspx?id=xx#/insidePartialOrTemplateView.html), I am not inside index.html as mentioned. Inside this partial view is some div/navigation/buttons/, where I want to load other views. So it will be like a whole new other website within the partial view I am currently on.

```
-------------------------------------
|profile |                          |
|settings|                          |
|gallery |  load views here         |
|        |                          |
|        |                          |
-------------------------------------
```

example code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="user">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=#/userProfile></a></li>
        <li><a href=#/userSettings></a></li>
        <li><a href=#/userGallery></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</script>
```

Also for routing in this case

```
angular.module("PageRouting", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/userProfile", {
                templateUrl: "sample1.html"
            })
            .when("/userSettings", {
                templateUrl: "sample2.html"
            })
            .when("/userGallery", {
                templateUrl: "sample3.html"
            })
    })
```

Is there a possible solution for this? I am using angular 1.5.  I am new to angular and don't know anything. I am not acquainted with higher versions.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can load as many templates inside each other as you want.
Here's an example with two:

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
  Content of the template.

  <a ng-click="currentTpl2='/tpl2.html'" id="tpl-link">Load inlined template2</a>

  <div id="tpl-content2" ng-include src="currentTpl2"></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl2.html">
    Content of the template2.
  </script>
</script>

<a ng-click="currentTpl='/tpl.html'" id="tpl-link">Load inlined template</a>
<div id="tpl-content" ng-include src="currentTpl"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking Interest. I found out that, what I was trying to do was not possible. Since there is already route pointing to my partial view, it wouldn't be possible to make route within that partial view.